# Proguard dontwarn and dontnote not taking effect

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I am building an Android project that has some buildTypes that are using Proguard. During the build I am seeing a ton of warnings from Proguard. Because these warnings are generated for third party classes that I am using I'm attempting to use the -dontwarn flag and -dontnote flag in my 'proguard-rules.pro' file so that I won't see the error output in the future. However, the issue I'm seeing is that even after I add these flags to my .pro file and specify the .pro file in the build.gradle I'm still seeing the warnings output when the project is built.

Here is the relevant part of the build.gradle file:

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }

        unitTest {
            applicationIdSuffix ".unittest"
            minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt")
            proguardFile('proguard-rules.pro')
        }

        automation {
            applicationIdSuffix ".automation"
            minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            proguardFile('proguard-rules.pro')

        }

        internal {
            applicationIdSuffix ".internal"
            minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            proguardFile('proguard-rules.pro')
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt")
            proguardFile("proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
```

Here's my proguard-rules.pro file:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Disabling obfuscation is useful if you collect stack traces from production crashes
# (unless you are using a system that supports de-obfuscate the stack traces).
-dontobfuscate

# React Native

# Keep our interfaces so they can be used by other ProGuard rules.
# See http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/466/
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters

# Do not strip any method/class that is annotated with @DoNotStrip
-keep @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip *;
}

-keepclassmembers @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters class * {
  void set*(***);
  *** get*();
}

-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule { *; }
-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule { *; }
-keepclassmembers,includedescriptorclasses class * { native <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIProp <fields>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup <methods>; }

-dontwarn com.facebook.react.**

# okhttp

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

# okio

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**

# stetho

-dontwarn com.facebook.stetho.**

##ADDED TO GET WARNINGS TO GO AWAY BUT NEEDS TO BE EVALED BEFORE RELEASE
-dontnote junit.runner.*
-dontnote junit.framework.*
-dontwarn org.hamcrest.**
-dontwarn android.support.test.**
```

Note the proguard-rules.pro file is located in my project/app/ directory next to the build.gradle file that references it.

Here's a snippet of the error output from gradle:

```
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.runner.Version]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.runner.BaseTestRunner]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.framework.Protectable]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.framework.Assert]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.framework.TestSuite]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.framework.Test]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.framework.ComparisonFailure]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.framework.TestFailure]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.framework.TestCase]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.framework.AssertionFailedError]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.framework.TestListener]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [junit.framework.TestResult]
Reading library jar [/Users/dhodapp/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]
Note: there were 19 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find superclass or interface org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher
Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.JMock1Adapter: can't find superclass or interface org.jmock.core.Constraint
Warning: library class android.test.AndroidTestCase extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
Warning: library class android.test.AndroidTestRunner extends or implements program class junit.runner.BaseTestRunner
Warning: library class android.test.InstrumentationTestCase extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
Warning: library class android.test.InstrumentationTestSuite extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestSuite
```

Why aren't the error messages being squashed when I apply the proguard-rules.pro file?